# Mass delete multiple Drupal nodes via PHP

Tags: php, drupal

I have created a script that connects to a Drupal 9 database, and then creates a table of the posts added in the last month (including some additional columns created joining some tables).

```
<?php

$envFile = __DIR__ . '/../.env';
if (file_exists($envFile)) {
    $envVariables = parse_ini_file($envFile);
    foreach ($envVariables as $key => $value) {
        putenv("$key=$value");
    }
}

$servername = getenv('DB_HOST');
$username = getenv('DB_USERNAME');
$password = getenv('DB_PASSWORD');
$dbname = getenv('DB_NAME');

// Create connection to MySQL server
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check if connection was successful
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Calculate the timestamp for one month ago
$oneMonthAgo = strtotime('-1 month');

// Retrieve the content from the table for posts created in the last month
$sql = "SELECT cr.entity_id, cr.field_response_content_value, cf.created, cf.status
        FROM comment__field_response_content AS cr
        INNER JOIN comment_field_data AS cf ON cr.entity_id = cf.cid
        WHERE cf.created >= $oneMonthAgo
        ORDER BY cr.entity_id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if connection was successful
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Calculate the timestamp for one month ago
$oneMonthAgo = strtotime('-1 month');

// Retrieve the content from the table for posts created in the last month
$sql = "SELECT cr.entity_id, cr.field_response_content_value, cf.created, cf.status
        FROM comment__field_response_content AS cr
        INNER JOIN comment_field_data AS cf ON cr.entity_id = cf.cid
        WHERE cf.created >= $oneMonthAgo
        ORDER BY cr.entity_id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if query execution was successful
if ($result) {
    // Check if the filter parameters are present in the URL
    $filterGibberish = isset($_GET['filter_gibberish']) ? $_GET['filter_gibberish'] : '';
    $filterStatusApproved = isset($_GET['filter_status_approved']) ? $_GET['filter_status_approved'] : '';
    $filterStatusUnapproved = isset($_GET['filter_status_unapproved']) ? $_GET['filter_status_unapproved'] : '';

    // Determine the filter checkbox states
    $gibberishChecked = $filterGibberish === 'yes' ? 'checked' : '';
    $statusApprovedChecked = $filterStatusApproved === 'yes' ? 'checked' : '';
    $statusUnapprovedChecked = $filterStatusUnapproved === 'yes' ? 'checked' : '';

    // Display the filter checkboxes
    echo '<br><form action="" method="GET" id="table-filters">';
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="filter_gibberish" value="yes" ' . $gibberishChecked . '>Gibberish</label>';
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="filter_status_approved" value="yes" ' . $statusApprovedChecked . '>Approved</label>';
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="filter_status_unapproved" value="yes" ' . $statusUnapprovedChecked . '>Unapproved</label>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Apply Filters">';
    echo '</form>';

    // Read the online file and store entity IDs in an array
    $onlineFileURL = "https://www.dropbox.com/somethingsomething.txt?dl=1";
    $gibberishEntityIDs = file($onlineFileURL, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    // Display the table header
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Post ID</th><th>Content</th><th>Date</th><th>Gibberish</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

    // Loop through the retrieved rows
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Access the entity_id, content, created, and status columns
        $entityId = $row['entity_id'];
        $content = $row['field_response_content_value'];
        $created = date('d M Y H:i', $row['created']);
        $status = $row['status'];

        // Check if entity_id is present in the online file
        $isGibberish = in_array($entityId, $gibberishEntityIDs) ? "yes" : "";

        // Apply the filters
        if (
            ($filterGibberish === 'yes' && $isGibberish !== 'yes') ||
            ($filterStatusApproved === 'yes' && $status !== '1') ||
            ($filterStatusUnapproved === 'yes' && $status !== '0')
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        // Increment the counter
        $rowCount++;

        // Convert the status value to "Unapproved" or "Approved"
        $statusText = $status === '0' ? "Unapproved" : "Approved";

        // Create the delete link using the entity_id
        $deleteLink = "https://website.com/comment/$entityId/delete";

        // Display the row content in a table row
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $entityId . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $content . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $created . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $isGibberish . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $statusText . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='" . $deleteLink . "'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

// Display the row count
echo "<p><strong>Number of posts: " . $rowCount . "</strong></p>";

// Close the table
echo "</table>";

// Free the result set
$result->free();
} else {
    // Query execution failed
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
    }
    
    // Close MySQL connection
    $conn->close();
    
    ?>
```

The last column has a "Delete" link which sends the user to a Drupal link that if visited allows to delete the post. Is there a way to delete multiple Drupal posts at once instead of having to click on "Delete" for each? I can add checkboxes instead of a link, but I am not sure how to then pass the information to Drupal so that the selected posts can get deleted.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using any of the drupal api or creating the table with a view?

Comment: Hi @2pha - yes, I need to combine information present in Drupal with some external sources (linking them based on the node ID) that's why I am building this outside of Drupal.

Comment: I would probably still recommend using views and it's bulk operations, then hooking into it's submit function to do anything custom you need. Without knowing what these "external sources" are, it's hard to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @2pha I have a Python script that generates 2 sets of .txt files with a list of node IDs (it uses machine learning to flag nodes based on the language of the post)... I am matching the nodes in the txt files with the nodes in the database and this code generates a table and allows users to filter nodes based on whether they appear in either of the 2 txt files.

Comment: I would still probably use views to generate the table you need which will allow you to have the bulk form and delete multiple at a time.. and then maybe preprocess the table that views outputs to inject data.columns from your txt files.

Comment: Another question you might want to ask yourself is do you want the user of the table/form to be logged in to the website.